# Odds of putting 5 wires into correct spot

Tags: probability

I just ran 5 speaker wires across my living room to the subwoofer where they connect. When they were all there, I had no idea which wire went to which speaker. By some miracle I got them all into the correct spot in the subwoofer on the first try. There were 5 spots in the subwoofer. What are the odds that this would happen?

I'm thinking it might be 1/5 * 1/4 * 1/3 * 1/2 = 1/120 but I've never been good with probability and I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: How many spots were there in the speaker?

Comment: 5 spots, one for each of the speakers I was trying to hook up.

Comment: Well then the answer you got was correct.

Answer (score 0):

The total ways of placing 5 wires in 5 spots is 5! =120 Out of which one way is correct that you have got by miracle. Thus the probability is $1/120$. Which is correct.